# Unitarity of Symmetrisation operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, many-body

How can i proove that the symmetrisation operators $S_{\pm}$ are unitary?

Defining $S_{\pm}$ on the $N$ Particle Fock Space by it's effect on $|\Psi \rangle=| \Psi_1 \rangle \otimes... \otimes| \Psi_N\rangle $

$$S_{\pm}|\Psi \rangle = { 1 \over \sqrt{ N !}} \sum \limits_{i\text{-th transposition}} (\pm1)^{\text{signum }(i)} \hat P_i |\Psi \rangle$$

Summing over all two particle exchanges. And assigning accordingly $+$ to Bosons and $-$ to Fermions. Where $\hat P_i$ is the particle exchange operator for the $i$-th transposition.

I would try to do this by trying to show that $\langle \Psi |S_{\pm}^\dagger S_{\pm} |\Psi \rangle=\langle \Psi  |\Psi \rangle$ holds.

It is certanly easily prooven that $\langle \Psi |P_i^\dagger P_i |\Psi \rangle=\langle \Psi  |\Psi \rangle$ but we will most of the time have  $\langle \Psi |P_i^\dagger P_j |\Psi \rangle$ in this sum. And please don't say it is easily absteactd from $N=2$ to any $N$ because i don't see how and because of this i am asking here.

Comment: The symmetrization operators are not unitary; they are orthogonal projections. It is easy to see that they are not unitary because if you take a symmetric state with norm one and you apply the antisymmetrizer you obtain the zero vector, and also applying the symm. to an antisymm. vector.

Comment: Also, the range of the symmetrization operators is a proper subset of the whole hilbert space, so they cannot be unitary operators.

Comment: interesting thanks.I assumed this because in one of my lectures this showes up $\langle \Psi |S_{\pm}^\dagger O(\hat x ,\hat p)  S_{\pm} |\Psi \rangle= \langle \Psi |O(\hat x ,\hat p)   |\Psi \rangle$. But I realized today while looking on here about the classical Limit, which was the topic of that part that $ \lim \hbar \to 0 $ does not cut it anyway so maybe there is more wrong in that section...